# Socrata distance_in_meters(...) returns errors even on 2.1 endpoint

Tags: socrata, soda

When I make a query from the [CMS Nursing Home Compare data](https://data.medicare.gov/Nursing-Home-Compare/Provider-Info/4pq5-n9py) and attempt to order using `distance_in_meters(...)` I get the following error:

> `Error: function distance_in_meters is not defined in SoQL.`

The docs say `distance_in_meters(...)` works with the 2.1 endpoint (further information on endpoints are stuck in a redirect loop from the link at the top of that page at the time of this writing but you can get it from Google cache): https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/distance_in_meters.html

I have confirmed the data set is [using the 2.1 endpoint](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.medicare.gov/b27b-2uc7).

To be sure it wasn't an issue with just the order clause, I also set it up in the select. Two variations:

1. https://data.medicare.gov/resource/4pq5-n9py.json?$select=*,%20distance_in_meters(location,%20%27POINT%20(-78.9627624%2043.0171854)%27)%20AS%20range&$where=within_circle(location,43.0171854,-78.9627624,16093.44)
2. https://data.medicare.gov/resource/4pq5-n9py.json?$where=within_circle(location,43.0171854,-78.9627624,16093.44)&$order=distance_in_meters(location,%20%27POINT%20(-78.9627624%2043.0171854)%27)

So, the question ultimately is does the 2.1 endpoint not support `distance_in_meters(...)` or am I missing something stupid obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like although you're looking at the API docs for the 2.1 endpoint, you're actually using the 2.0 one in your queries. You should use:

```
https://data.medicare.gov/resource/b27b-2uc7.json
```

... instead of:

```
https://data.medicare.gov/resource/4pq5-n9py.json
```

I change the root endpoint to the 2.1 version, and the query looks like it returns the results you'd expect:

```
https://data.medicare.gov/resource/b27b-2uc7.json?$where=within_circle(location,43.0171854,-78.9627624,16093.44)&$order=distance_in_meters(location,%20%27POINT%20(-78.9627624%2043.0171854)%27)
```

Comment: Ugh. I have no idea how I ended up on the 2.0 endpoint data set. When I follow instructions to get to the endpoint details, I didn't realize the different value (b27b-2uc7) was a different endpoint as it showed the same data and came from the 2.0 endpoint data (4pq5-n9py).

Comment: Don't worry, its a common point of confusion. If you got the endpoint from the API sidebar more than a couple of weeks ago, you probably grabbed the old endpoint. The dataset page uses the old API endpoint, so we used to list that there.

Comment: Yeah, I grabbed that in February (and then this project got shelved for a while). If I may, I have a feature request: provide info that a more current version is available. We struggle with this all the time at W3C and users grabbing wrong version of a document.